# How to display horizontal list view items with the adapted size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the horizontal list view to adapt to his child height and auto-resize.
Here my code :

```
 return Swiper(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return savedPostItems[index];
                },
                itemCount: savedPostItems.length,
                viewportFraction: 0.8,
                scale: 0.9,
                loop: false,
                itemWidth: 450,
                itemHeight: 300,
                layout: SwiperLayout.TINDER,
              );
```

I'm using the flutter swiper package but it basically work like a horizontal listview.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Will it not already do that if you take off the itemHeight property?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do what i wanted.
I use a column:

```
Container(
                height: 300,
                child: Swiper(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        savedPostItems[index],
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: savedPostItems.length,
                  viewportFraction: 0.8,
                  scale: 0.9,
                  loop: false,
                ),
              );
```